Port mapping from the internet to a local server
I am attempting to access my home server from the internet. This is my first time attempting to make a server, on a local network, accessible from the internet.
I expect the process to be:

User requests 'My.Modem.External.IP:Port'
My modem sees the request and translates this request to 'My.Internal.Server.IP:AnotherPort'
Request is passed onto the internal server, answered, passed back to the modem, and finally back to the user.

Logging into my modem, I navigate to 'NAT > Port Forwarding' and am presented with the following editable options. The values I enter are:
Status: Active
ServiceName: MyCustomName
Originating IP: [Blank]
WAN Interface: WWAN
Server IP Address: My.Internal.Server.IP
Start Port: 8080
End Port: 8082
Translation Start Port: 80
Translation End Port: 82
Protocol: TCP

After tinkering, I have come to the belief that the range [Start Port] through [End Port] corresponds to the range of ports on the modem. Similarly, I believe the range [Translation Start Port] through [Translation End Port] corresponds to the range of ports on the internal server.
If I visit request port 80 on my local IP address, I am shown my webpage as I expect.
However, if I request 'My.Modem.External.IP:8080', which I would expect to map through to 'My.Server.Internal.IP:80', my browser times out and says it 'can't establish a connection'.
Is there an error in my reasoning above, or something I am missing ?
Update
Following @Grawity's advice, I have:
(1) Tried accessing my external IP from outside my LAN. Unfortunately, this request times out.
(2) Looked into the possibility of my provider placing me behind a CGNAT.
In achieving (2), I have found, listed on my routers portal:
WAN Information (Ethernet WAN)
Name: ETHWAN
Encapsulation: IPoE
IP Address: [IP Address 2]
IP Subnet Mask: [Value]
Primary DNS Server: [Value]
Secondary DNS Server: [Value]

Where the IP address labelled as [IP Address 2] above, is different to the IP address I find when I search my IP on the internet. This leads me to conclude that I am behind a CGNAT.
Does anyone have guidance how to resolve this issue ?

Are you making the test requests from within LAN or from some external system (i.e. from the WWAN side)? What kind of physical connection is WWAN, anyway? (And is it the same CGNAT-using ISP that you asked a few months earlier?)

(1) I make the test request to the external IP of my modem, not to the internal IP of my server. (2) I am not sure what WWAN is. (3) I am not sure whether this is a CGNAT-using ISP, or how I could tell.

(1) the question was from where, not to where, i.e. from inside your LAN or from outside, NOT to which IP. (2) Maybe you should google a bit before posting a non-reply? (3) again, google it or ask them directly. Also it should be obvious simply looking at your public IP.

It's almost definitely one of two very commonly asked about problems;
If the test request is made from LAN
In step 3 of the process, the reply has to undergo the opposite translation, i.e. because the reply is coming from 'Your.Internal.Server.IP:AnotherPort' the modem (router) has to rewrite its source to 'Your.Modem.External.IP:Port' for the client to recognize it.
When you request this from the 'LAN' side, the server sees that the client is on the same subnet and will send the reply directly to the client's MAC address, without the packet going through the modem (router) as a gateway. (It might still go through the modem's Ethernet switch, but generally not through its IP stack.)
As a result, the modem doesn't have the opportunity to perform the reverse translation on replies, so what the client sees is a packet from a completely different address:port than what it actually tried to connect to, and what it doesn't see is any kind of reply from 'Your.Modem.External.IP:Port' that it's waiting for.
Check if the modem (router) has a "NAT hairpin" or "NAT loopback" feature. This would cause it to additionally translate the client's IP address, making it look to the server like the request came from the router, and therefore tricking the server into replying to (through) the router.
If the test request is made from WAN
The other most common problem is that 'Your.Modem.External.IP' is not actually the modem's IP address. Many ISPs put their customers behind CGNAT – a second layer of NAT, managed by the ISP – due to the general IPv4 address shortage, and in those cases the external IP address belongs to the ISP's NAT gateway which often has no inbound NAT rules at all (or sometimes has a very limited port range mapped inbound), and the initial packet from 'user' never even reaches the modem.
Your WAN interface is named WWAN, which usually means LTE/4G/5G where CGNAT is probably near-universal, but it is becoming just as common for other Internet connection types.

Thankyou for the guidance Grawity. I have followed up on your 2 suggestions and will edit my original question. In short, requesting from outside my LAN did not work, and I believe I am behind a CGNAT.

In that case, it's definitely not going to work due to CGNAT. (See e.g. older topics.)
